# PHP + Javascript :Use quotes within quotes within quotes

Tags: javascript, php

There are a few questions on here on quotes within quotes within quotes, but none have the solution for me.

(I think) I need 'real' quotes within quotes within quotes

My scenario is thus:

```
 <?php echo   "<script>text=/"<a onclick=\'myFunction('php-variable')\'>click me</a>/"</script>" ?>
```

The browser output would be:

```
<script>text="<a onclick='myFunction('argument')'>click me</a>"</script>
```

Comment: I don't see any reason why `&quot;` wouldn't work here. You haven't included an [mcve] showing your effort though.

Comment: You can use `\\` to escape backslashes.

Comment: <?php echo "<script>text=\"<a onclick=\'myFunction('argument')\'>click me</a>\"</script>"?> works just fine.... what is the output you get? to say it hasn't worked?
  
it outputs what you expect.... http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/18ce026929d8d9b48b68a884aca411012cfd17fc

Comment: @Juan — You can't use literal `'` characters inside an HTML attribute value delimited with `'` characters.

Comment: You're doing something very wrong. First, you can drop out of PHP mode to output stuff, so just `?><script>...</script><?php` will work. Then, you shouldn't be using inline event handlers. Finally, you should be using DOM methods to create your elements. But because you're doing it so wrong, you're instead messing around trying to get nine thousand backslashes...

Comment: @Quentin good point. I just based my comment on OP's "The browser output would be:" and compared it to the result. I didn't look any further.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol I need this in php because there is a php variable in the argument, I have edited the question

Comment: So stick the PHP data in a JavaScript variable and then use DOM as Niet said. Generating HTML with embedded JS with embedded HTML with embedded JS with embedded dynamic data is just asking for trouble.

Comment: You're still doing it wrong. `?><script>var a = document.createElement('a'); a.onclick = function() {myFunction(<?=json_encode($PHP_variable)?>);}; ... </script><?php`

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol can you add this as an answer please?

Comment: No, because it's not an "answer" to your question. I'm literally shooting your question down and telling you why you've strayed down the wrong path. This question should be deleted, IMO.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol well you are wrong because I had a problem and you have helped me solve it. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Quentin, thanks - using the DOM and putting the php variable into a javascript variable, makes sense. I just don't understand why you can't put it in an answer, instead downvoting and trashing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a commenter (who didn't post an answer) I have taken the script code out of the `<?php ?>` and only used it where necessary.

`<script>text="<a onclick=\'myFunction('<?php echo $PHP_variable ?>')\'>click me</a>"</script>`

The quotes nest as thus

```
" , /" , '
```

(Whereas before I was nesting quotes 4 times)

Comment: Also, putting the PHP data in a JavaScript variable and then use DOM is useful, as suggested

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
echo "<script>text=\"<a onclick='myFunction(\\\"argument\\\")'>click me</a>\";document.write(text);</script>";
```

I've tested it.

Comment: An explanation as to what you changed, why, and how it works would raise this from "a lump of code" into an actual answer.

Comment: I think I'm silly. But it may be a good exercise of writing `string` for some people, ... and me.